# <T extends Error> not resolving in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface IErrorIdentification {
  errorClass?: new <T extends Error>() => T;
  code?: string;
  name?: string;
  messageContains?: string;
}
```

The `errorClass` property, however, is giving me fits. When using this code:

```
context.errorMeta.add(
  404,
  { errorClass: HandledError },
  { callback: e => cbResult }
);
```

Where the second parameter -- `{ errorClass: HandledError }` -- is typed to **IErrorIdentificaiton** I get the following error:

[image: error]

It works as expected at run time with the following check:

```
e instanceof i.identifiedBy.errorClass
```

The error (`e`) also tests positive as an *instance of* `Error` which makes sense considering `HandledError` is defined as:

```js
export class HandledError extends Error { ... }
```

Given all this, i'm unsure why I'm getting an error at all and the error text isn't helping me. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
errorClass?: new <T extends Error>() => T;
```

This doesn't mean what you think it means. It means "`errorClass` should be a generic thing on which I can invoke `new` and get *any* error type of my choice." That is, *for all* `T` extending `Error`, `new` should be able to return a `T`. `HandledError` doesn't satisfy this, because it can't return, say, `TypeError` or any other type of error. In all honesty, I'm not sure Typescript has any way of constructing a (non-`any`) value which satisfies that constraint.

What you want is something that says "there exists some `T` for which `new` returns a `T`". That's called an existential type, which Typescript does not support. So you have a couple of options. If you don't care about the specific type of error, just drop the facade and have `new` return `Error`.

```
export interface IErrorIdentification {
  errorClass?: new() => Error;
}
```

On the other hand, if you *really* need the `T` value for whatever reason, parameterize your interface.

```
export interface IErrorIdentification<T extends Error> {
  errorClass?: new() => T;
}
```

Comment: So the reason that I wanted to avoid just using `Error` is that some extended errors include other parameters (like `code` or in AWS `httpStatus`). I did try moving the generic to the interface level but in doing so it no longer can implicitly sort out the type of the **errorClass** which is a problem because errorClass is optional and in most use-cases is not the means used to identify the error.

Comment: Ok, if I use `<T extends Error = Error>` I remove the need to state the type `T` while giving the opportunity to implicitly find the extended Error class if it's stated.

Comment: It appears I spoke a bit too soon ... it does work in runtime (as it did before) ... but I still do get the error. In fact even with the dreaded `any` operator I get the error.

Comment: You need to think about what you want. If you want to know the specific error type, you need to have a generic parameter, and then an `IErrorIdentification<TypeError>` is fundamentally different from an `IErrorIdentification<HandlerError>`. If you don't care, then go with the other solution and treat everything as `Error`. What if you want to access that AWS `httpStatus` but I give you a `TypeError`? Without the generic argument, the type system can't verify what you want it to verify.

Comment: So it turns out the `new() => Error` is fine but what was needed was `new(...args:any[]) => Error` to allow for different constructor shapes.